# How to make Dotenv and Nock work together?

Tags: javascript, nock, dotenv

Currently in one of my apps i am using nock to mock my api request.Unfortunately in another test file of same project, i used dotenv.If i use dotenv my nock is not mocking the url, it is using the original api request.
Any suggestions or help is appreciated.
**My test file**

```js
'use strict';

const assert = require('assert');
const nock = require('nock');

describe('example', () => {
  afterEach(async() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  describe("checktest", () => {

    it("checksomeupdate", async() => {
      nock('http://example.com')
        .get('/demend-point')
        .reply(200, {
          x: 1
        })

      const result = await demoCallToMainFileMetho();
      const [a, b] = result || []; // response array [1,2,3]
      assert.ok(a.includes('1'));
    });
  });
});
```

**My other file in test dir**

```
require('dotenv').config();
.....some code
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking, could you provide minimal code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski
in my demo.test.js
require('dotenv');
.....some code
in my demo1.test.js
if i nock('http://example.com')....some code
it does not wrok.

Comment: i'm afraid i do not have access to your `demo.test.js` and i don't know what its contents are. On top of that i'm pretty sure this one file may not be enough to reproduce the issue

Comment: @OmarFaruqueSohag, I'm afraid we are still missing some relevant code. What are the configuration you are loading through the `require('dotenv').config()` statement? What is the call executed in `demoCallToMainFileMetho` method?

Comment: require('dotenv').config() is helping to appear process.env variables as those are being used in another files. @mgarcia

Comment: I understand that, but what variables are being defined? Are those variables being used in `demoCallToMainFileMetho` method? Please, provide more context/code so that we can help you better.

Comment: Yes. You are right.Say in my .env i have USER_NAME=<replace>,In my  demoCallToMainFileMetho  this variable is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is fixed.
Solution: I had to remove dotenv package from my script.Where ever i needed that i had to replace with

```js
process.env = Object.assign(process.env, 
    { DEMO_VARIABLE_ONE: 'false' },
    { DEMO_VARIABLE_ONE_URL: 'value' },
    { DEMO_VARIABLE_TWO: 'value' }
);
```